# String translation with or without po file

Tags: translation

I want to update some translation but it seems all translations are save in *.po file. I update that file but no update appears in website, can you help me to make updates?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the .po files are just the human readable version of the translation, but it is not actually used by wordpress for anything. What you need is to generate a .mo version (it is the .po file in some binary encoding form) with a tool like poedit.